Degree Sequence Conditions for Hamiltonicity in Bipartite Graphs
The background is Bondy & Murty GT244 p.490 Exercise 18.3.9

18.3.9 Let $G := G[X, Y]$ be a simple bipartite graph, where $|X| = |Y| \geq 2$, with degree sequence $(d_1, d_2, \dots , d_n)$, where $d_1 \leq d_2 \leq \cdots \leq d_n$. Suppose that there is no integer $k \leq n/4$ such that $d_k \leq k$ and $d_{n/2} \leq n/2 − k$. Show that G is Hamiltonian.

I have no idea on it. There's a theorem in the book that's supposed to be relevant to the problem, but I don't know how to apply the theorem to solve the problem.

Theorem 18.9 Let $G$ be a simple graph with degree sequence $(d_1, d_2, \dots , d_n)$, where $d_1 \leq d_2 \leq \cdots \leq d_n$ and $n \geq 3$. Suppose that there is no integer $k < n/2$ such that $d_k \leq k$ and $d_{n−k} < n − k$. Then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

And there is a hint about it:

18.3.9 Form a new graph $H$ from $G$ by adding edges between all pairs of vertices of $X$. Show that $H$ is Hamiltonian if and only if $G$ is Hamiltonian.

But if I can join every pairs of vertices of $X$, then I can't determine which numbers in the degree sequence will be added $n/2-1$, and then I don't know how to use theorem 18.9. On the other hand, if I can prove the closure of this bipartite graph is complete or complete bipartite, then problem is solved, but I have no idea to deal with it.
Any comments or answers welcome.

Whether you take the hint or not, you're not going to get out of having to deal with the diffficulty of not knowing which numbers in the degree sequence come from which side of the graph. On the other hand, the closure of this bipartite graph (and most balanced bipartite graphs) is likely to be the graph itself; this will happen, in particular, if no vertex has degree $n/2$, which we cannot rule out.
